# Implementation of hierarchy of categories

Tags: iphone, ios4, uinavigationcontroller

I have task to implement hierarchy of Category->Sub-Category->Offer->Offer Details. But I'm not sure how to do this. I should use JSON to fill date. My idea is the root controller "CategoriesController" to make HTTP request to the server and parse the response and names of the cells to be rows of my table view. But I don't know how to second controller "SubCategoriesController" to know who is him parent. I mean how to make the request to return me only categories that are children of the selected category. Please give me some guidelines.

Thanks :)

Comment: You mean when user selects a Category (from table), you want to show its sub category in SubCategory table view and how SubCategory would know which category was selected?

Comment: Can you have a property in your SubCategory something as "selectedCategory" and before you present or push your SubCategory view controller, set it to appropriate value?

Comment: Should this property be static?

Answer (score 0):

I have done this like follows:

Table structure should be like:

Category_id, parent_category_id, category_name, etc

All main categories should have parent_category_id = 0
So when you want to load all the main categories you will load where parent_category_id = 0
Similarly all categories will have category_id in their parent_category_id.

**Example:

Apparels->Ready Made->Pent->Skinny**

Apparels is parent of Ready Made
Ready made is parent of Pent
Pent is parent of Skinny

So in DB is should be like this

**Name        : category_id    : parent_category_id**

Apparels    : 1              : 0 (This does not have any parent)
Ready made  : 2              : 1
Pent        : 3              : 2
Skinny      : 4              : 3

So if you want to know the parent of Skinny you will check the value in parent_category_id that is 3 for this example then you will check the category_id = 3 and that is Pent which is correct for this example.

I hope this will help you :)

Thanks.